# I'm trying to replace a specific value in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a row that consists of days of the week but there is a random number in there and i just want to replace that number with "Thur" i tried . replace but my then all the other columns in my df disappeared except for the index and the column that had the days of the week

```
sales=sales["day of week"].replace(0, "Thru")
```

^^^this is the code i used
[image: this is the df before i ran the code]
this is the df before i ran the code

[image: This is the df after i ran the code]

This is the df after i ran the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign only the `day of week` column into `sales`, so it makes sense you get only one column. Try:

```
sales["day of week"]=sales["day of week"].replace(0, "Thru")
```

If it doesn't work (because `day of week` is an `object` type column), try:

```
sales["day of week"]=sales["day of week"].replace('0', "Thru")
```

Answer (score 2):

In pandas, replacing values can be done with `.loc`.

In your case the following should work:

```
sales.loc[sales["day of week"] == 0, "day of week"] = "Thru"
```